# Maven Tycho + Nexus deployment error

Tags: maven, deployment, nexus, tycho, repository

I'm trying to deploy a Multi-Module maven project with the following structure to a Nexus server (with p2 support and the target repository configured as Snapshot and with proper settings.xml credentials):

- PARENT PROJECT (empty, only pom definition)

  - MODULE PROJECT A
  - MODULE PROJECT B

mvn install produces a satisfactory build, the problem is when I try to deploy PARENT PROJECT, it shows the following errors:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ PARENT PROJECT ---
[INFO] Installing C:\PATH-TO-PARENT-PROJECT\pom.xml to C:\PATH-TO LOCAL-REPO\PATH-TO-PARENT-PROJECT\1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\PARENT-PROJECT-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project PARENT PROJECT: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact PARENT PROJECT:pom:1.0.0-20131022.102942-1 in deployment-server (http://DEPLOYMENT-SRV/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots) -> [Help 1]
```

I can deploy each sub module independently running mvn deploy on them, but when i run it on PARENT PROJECT it gives me that error. The parent pom is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ID</groupId>
    <artifactId>PARENT-PROJECT</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <tycho-version>0.18.1</tycho-version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>MODULE PROJECT A</module>
        <module>MODULE PROJECT B</module>
    </modules>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>eclipse-juno</id>
            <layout>p2</layout>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno</url>
        </repository>


        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://DEPLOYMENT-SRV/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/.meta/p2</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resolver>p2</resolver>
                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>${build.os}</os>
                            <ws>${build.ws}</ws>
                            <arch>${build.arch}</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assemble/bin.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <testClassesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</testClassesDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <url>http://DEPLOYMENT-SRV/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Thankyou!